# Smallest path from corner to corner of a 2D array

Tags: java, algorithm, queue, breadth-first-search

I'm working on a problem where I'm trying to get from the top left corner, i.e. (0,0), to the bottom right, or (m - 1, n - 1), of an input m x n 2D array. Additionally, each element of the array represents what kind of jumps can be made from that square.

For example, a table that looks like:

1 2 1

1 1 1

1 1 1

Would have a minimum path of 3, since you can go from (0,0), jump 1 square right to (0,1), jump 2 squares down to (2, 1), then jump 1 square right to the destination of (2, 2).

My current implementation uses BFS, where I push each unvisited connected square into a queue, going through until I reach the corner or am unable to proceed; along the way, I update a seperate 2D array that contains the number of moves it takes to reach that particular coordinate on the actual board from the starting square.

My code works for many of the tests I throw at it, but for a few seemingly random test cases, it returns the wrong number of moves (higher than the actual number by quite a bit). I have no idea why this might be the case! Any suggestions on where I might have gone wrong would be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you add the cases for which the solution fails?

Comment: I think your problem is that you mark nodes as visited, so that you don't consider them on "later" paths, even if they were reached with fewer steps the second (or third, or fourth ...) time round. Of course, exploring all possible paths would be a waste of time. Perhaps you could use a criterion where you check whether the new distance would be smaller than the previous one instead of barring visited nodes.

Comment: @MOehm But I think that's appropriate for BFS right? Since the first time you reach a particular node in this procedure, it's always going to be the minimum number of moves it would have taken to reach that node.

Comment: @OsamaAbdulRehman It passes all the simple cases, but starts messing up at very complex boards (like 50x5 or 500x500), though it still passes a few of the large ones too.

Comment: It would be correct if all your steps had the same length. Your variable step length breaks that.

Comment: @MOehm I think you're right that this is the problem, but I just can't figure out an example of a board that would demonstrate this. Do you think you have one in mind? That's what bugging me, I can't even properly debug it because all the test cases I fail right now are so large and complex!

Comment: I haven't tested it, but think about a 5×6 grid with the top row `15111`, the bottom row `41111` and all other rows `11111`. The shortest path would have 4 steps: e, s (5), w, e (4). Your algorithm goes south first and will probably go s, s, s, s, s, e (4). That case may even be too simple, because you will reach the southwest square on the short path first. Perhaps the problem only shows with complex cases, but that's how to construct such cases: Try to reach nodes on various paths. Also, the solutions show a symmatry: A transposed maze should give the same answer as the original maze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are updating the distanceArray without setting that square as visited (which normally would prevent overwriting that square in distanceArray), and only mark it as visited once that square reaches the top of the queue. This means that it's possible for another path ahead in the queue to overwrite that distance before it gets marked as visited.

Here's an example of this problem

```
Board:
1 1 1 1  
1 2 1 1  
1 1 1 1  
1 2 1 1
```

```
Queue:   0,0 1,0 0,1 2,0 1,1 1,1 0,2 3,0 2,1 *3,1* 1,3 1,2 0,3 *3,1*   
Distance: 0   1   1   2   2   2   2   3   3   *3*   3   3   3   *4*
```

As you can see visiting 1,1 enqueues 3,1 with distance 3, but then visiting 3,0 also enqueues 3,1 and overwrites its distance to 4, because 3,1 hasn't reached the top of the queue and isn't considered visited yet.

There are multiple ways of fixing this. The simplest is probably to just set it as visited as you enqueue it. However this isn't quite viable in your exact situation since you use the board to mark visited. So instead you'll probably want to store the visited information elsewhere. You could change the board squares from ints to an object that also holds their visited information as well as their step value (and while you're at it add their shortest path distance).
Alternatively if you don't want to rewrite a lot of your previous code you could just make another 2D array to store visited information, similar to your distanceArray.

You are also adding east to the queue twice. This shouldn't cause any problems but is worth addressing anyways

Comment: That was exactly it, thank you for the very clear board that demonstrated this.

Comment: Do you have any tips on setting it as visited properly in my current implementation? Currently, if I change the value to -1 (representing it as visited) while enqueing it, it would make it impossible for me to later use that value when that coordinate comes up in the queue.

I was thinking of using a node class, but maybe there's an easier way.

Right now, I'm just using a for loop to check through the coordinates of the queue every time before enqueing, which is very inefficient of course.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that you were using the board as a visited space as well. A node class is a pretty good way. If you don't want to rewrite a lot of your previous code you could also just make a visited board similar to your distance board. The former is probably a better practice but the latter will be easier to do given your current situation.